# Find and replace word causing duplication

Tags: javascript, replace, find, contains

I'm trying to loop through a set of DOM elements/buttons.
I then want to find a particular word and replace it with two words.

This works in almost all scenarios.

For example, the following code will change the text of the divs to "APPLES".

```
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("main-buttons");

    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        var res = buttons[i].innerHTML.replace(/ORANGE/gi, "APPLES");
        buttons[i].innerHTML = res;
    };
```

However, I am having a problem, when I want to replace "ORANGE" with "ORANGE BALLOONS".

**Instead of seeing the words "ORANGE BALLOONS" in my buttons.  I see "ORANGE BALLOONS BALLOONS".**

```
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("main-buttons");

    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        var res = buttons[i].innerHTML.replace(/ORANGE/gi, "ORANGE BALLOONS");
        buttons[i].innerHTML = res;
    };
```

I know this has something to do with the regex and my loop catching onto "orange", but I wondered if there was a better way to find and replace in javascript.

Or find a word and add another one next to it.

Comment: what was your text before seeing "ORANGE BALLOONS BALLOONS"?

Comment: @GabrielLupu - It was just "ORANGE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negative lookahead for `BALLOONS` when matching `ORANGE` to make sure existing `ORANGE BALLOONS` doesn't get changed:

```
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.main-buttons')) {
  button.innerHTML = button.innerHTML.replace(
    /ORANGE(?! BALLOONS)/gi,
    'ORANGE BALLOONS'
  );
}
```

If each of these elements contains text only, also change the `innerHTML` to `textContent` - better to only use `innerHTML` with HTML markup. (in the case of plain text, `.textContent` is more appropriate, faster, and safer)